# Append Dataframe inside the loop - Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying append dataframe inside the loop after reading the file, but still not appending full dataset.

```
columns = list(df)
data= []

for file in glob.glob("*.html"):
   df = pd.read_html(file)[2]
   
   zipped_date = zip(columns , df.values)
        
   a_dictionary = dict(zipped_date)
        
   data.append(a_dictionary)

full_df = full_df .append(data, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a list of dataframes inside the loop and the concat them:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.html"):
   data.append( pd.read_html(file)[2] )

full_df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.concat:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_html(file)[2] for files in glob.glob("*.html")])
```